# On iPhone Plus version UISplitViewController crashes on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have such situation:

- `UISplitViewController` as main navigation of application
- master - detail design, i.e. iPad master VC is side by side detail VC 
  on iPhone Master with Menu presents using `showDetailViewController()` detail view controllers.

on all iPhones and iPads everything works great, but on iPhone Plus it crashes when I have Detail VC on screen and try to rotate from portrait to landscape. As I run directly from menu to detail VC being already in landscape than I have side-by-side view controllers.

The code is so simple and basic that I cannot find any errors. It only throws error like this:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS on @UIApplicationMain AppDelegate

  0x112a82804 <+115>: callq  0x112a82869               ; _UIApplicationMainPreparations
    0x112a82809 <+120>: movq   0xceb190(%rip), %rdi      ; UIApp
    0x112a82810 <+127>: movq   0xc5f841(%rip), %rsi      ; "_run"
    0x112a82817 <+134>: callq  *0x892c93(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010906fd80: objc_msgSend
->  0x112a8281d <+140>: movq   0x892c94(%rip), %rbx      ; (void *)0x000000010906d010: objc_release
```

**UPDATE:**

I have made simple starter project with simplified navigation flow. One single showDetailViewController call from Master VC to Detail VC. And even then it crashes so it seems to not work on iPhone Plus phones. It seems like UISplitViewController bug. I think some solution will be to set on iPhone Plus devices to enforce collapsing (not side-by-side) while in landscape mode. I think there is possibility to set size classes (override default one) for landscape for UISplitView via delegation. Anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]